# how to search a list by name and another list inside it

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i have a list  `List<Technican> list;`

where Technican has the attributes:

```
class Technican{
    String name, status;
    int nbHired, nbStar;
    List<String> skills;
}
```

i want to search the list by name of the technician and his skills so for example

```
Technican(
                name: "Yehya Hijazi",
                nbStar: 1,
                nbHired: 107,
                status: 'Unavailable',
                skills: [
                  "Replacement"
                ]
            ),
```

so the result must :
when I write in the text field "Yehya" the tech will appear and when I write "replacement" the technician will appear

The search text field where on Changed :

```
onChanged: (value) {
   var trimedvalue = value.trim();
   setState(() {
      newList = techs
        .where(
          (string) =>string.name.toLowerCase().contains(trimedvalue.toLowerCase()) ||
           string.skills.toString().toLowerCase().contains(trimedvalue.toLowerCase()))
        )
        .toList();
   });
}
```

the first condition is working when searching name but no result on the second.

can any one help me

Comment: i coud'nt find any problem in your code .itested giving both result

Comment: did u test it online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to convert the **skills** array to a **string**, you could easily do:

```
var trimmedvalue = 'Replacement';

var newList = techs.where(
    (t) => t.name!.toLowerCase().contains(trimedvalue.toLowerCase()) ||
 t.skills!.map((s) => s.toLowerCase()).contains(trimedvalue.toLowerCase())).toList();
 print(newList);
```

Also you could change that variable called **string** and call it **tech** or something like that (for better readability); just a suggestion.

Proof that it works, run this on DartPad.dev https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/67e3243cb80b48fa15d9347402cb5cca

Comment: so the code will be newList = techs
                            .where(
                              (t) =>
                                t.name.toLowerCase().contains(trimedvalue.toLowerCase()) ||
                                t.skills.map((s) => s.toLowerCase()).contains(trimedvalue.toLowerCase())
                            )
                            .toList();

Comment: is that true or no

Comment: Correct. the full code should be just like you did it

Comment: did n't work :(

Comment: I ran your code on DartPad and it worked for me. Here's the DartPad Gist. Hit "Run" and You'll see. https://dartpad.dev/?67e3243cb80b48fa15d9347402cb5cca; I will update my answer so it is clearer.

Comment: emm is the ! mark necessary? cz i can't use it my project

Comment: Not necessary, because DartPad by default promotes null safety. You can remove those from your code and you should be good. Although whenever you're ready, I'd say migrate your code to Null Safety. You will thank me ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242246/discussion-between-roman-jaquez-and-isso-kd).